# How save value from a getValueAt - Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, mouselistener, tablemodel

I have a table and whenever I click on a cell of the table read its value. 
I want to store this data in an arraylist or something so you can take this information to another form of my application.

Is this possible? 
Does anyone could help me please? 
Thank you very much.

Code where I get the value from jTable

```
jMyTable.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {  

       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {         
        { 
            int selectedRowIndex = jMyTable.getSelectedRow();
            int selectedColumnIndex = jMyTable.getSelectedColumn();
            Object selectedObject = (Object) jMyTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
            System.out.println(selectedObject);
            }
                });  
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this (sample for Java 7 syntax):

```
List<Object> objs = new ArrayList<>();
jMyTable.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {  

   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {         
    { 
        int selectedRowIndex = jMyTable.rowAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        int selectedColumnIndex = jMyTable.columnAtPoint(e.getPoint());
        Object selectedObject = jMyTable.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
        objs.add(selectedObject);
        System.out.println(selectedObject);
        }
            });  
}
```

Comment: aaach valid untill JTables view isn't sorted or filtered

Comment: @mKorbel mea maxima culpa

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. worked very well. Now how can I bring this subject to another form of my application?

Comment: Please explain what you mean. Which subject and what a form?

Comment: Thanks for reply again. I get to do what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

you could implement ListSelectionListener.

//add a listener to retieve the row selected to be updated. put this in a constructor

```
  ListSelectionModel selectionModel = jTable1.getSelectionModel();
  selectionModel.addListSelectionListener(this);
```

//implement the method of the interface

```
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
    if(evt.getSource() == jTable1.getSelectionModel() &&
          evt.getValueIsAdjusting()){
      TableModel model = (TableModel)jTable1.getModel();
      Integer i =(Integer)model.getValueAt(jTable1.getSelectedRow(), 0);
```

then i guess you have a database. 
       //create an object of the database, find the selected row and retrieve the info

```
     DBManager db = new DBManager();

      CoachTrip c = db.findById(i);//here you retrieve the info and can store at any array or object 

      db.close();//close database if you have any
```

In this way it will work

Answer (score -1):

create a global array  and an integer

```
Object[] objs = new Object[];
int counter = 0;
```

on each mouse click do this instead of system.out.println

```
objs[counter] = (Object) jMyTable.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, selectedColumnIndex);
counter++;
```

counter tells the array at what point to store the next received object. When cell is first clicked it will store the object at 0 index in array, then on 1 and so on. Counter is required for the code to work

Comment: Thanks for reply. I dont  want to keep the number of clicks. 
I want to store the string that is the cell where i click. 

Basically want to keep my selectedObject.